# VMware, 2 Machines on 1 laptop IP issue

Tags: vmware-player

I have a laptop with 1 LAN card port, that i plug to a switch.
That switch is connected also to a server.

If i ping the server from my laptop, i get reply
when i opened the VMs, i get weird ip dynamically.
instead of the normal 192.168.1.XXX (DHCP) i got 192.168.192.128
and the other VM got 192.168.192.129.

If i ping my laptop which is at 192.168.1.7 or the server 192.168.1.100 from one of the VMS then it get reply, but if i try to ping 192.168.192.128 from the 192.168.192.129 VM.. i dont get replay.

So.. i have connection between the VMS and my laptop/server, but i dont have connection between my VMs.. how can i fix it ?
i choose NAT on the VM setting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a virtual machine in VMware you can selected if they use bridge network or if you want to use a local network.

If you select bridged than the appear as normal hosts on your network and get their IP from your normal DHCP server. There should not be any conflicts.

The other setting uses a local network and its own network range.

Check these settings.

Comment: I checked "Bridged: connected directly to the physical network" on both VMs, but they get dhcp ip that looks good like: 192.168.1.5 (sequential numbering). If i ping my laptop / other VM, i dont get reply, if i ping the gateway / server that attached to same switch - i get reply

Comment: OK, i used bridged connection, and then it worked ok. the problem i guess was to shutdown the windows firewall. now i can ping each VM from the other VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply manually assign an unused IP from the 192.168.1.X subnet to each VM That would be a quick and easy fix.

Comment: I tried, i do not know the DNS Server to enter in the IPV4 setting.. so if i just enter the IP address, mask and gateway - then the VMs dont communicate with each other and dont communicate with the laptop/server also..